# Family relation in prolog: hasNoChild(X) method

Tags: prolog

I have a database in prolog like this:

```
parent('John',Elizabeth').
parent('Mary',Elizabeth').
```

where the first name is the name of the parent and the second name is the name of the child. I need to create a method like:

```
hasNoChildren(X).
```

that gives me the list of all parents, that don`t have children. I have the method

```
hasChildren(X) :- parent(X, Y).
```

that do opposite things. I tried this:

```
hasNoChildren(X) :- \+ hasChildren(X).
```

but this doesn`t work for me. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Well negation does not bind, since in Prolog negation is semantically seen as "finite failure".

Comment: Your main problem is that you don't have a way of detecting if someone exists or is a person apart from their children. You'd need a predicate like `person(X) :- parent(X, _) ; parent(_, X).` and then you could say `hasNoChildren(X) :- person(X), \+ hasChildren(X).`